# Element of area in hyperbolic plane with polar coordinates on hyperboloid model

Tags: area, polar-coordinates, hyperbolic-geometry

The hyperbolic plane in the hyperboloid model in polar coordinates is the set of points (t,x,y) with $$x = r \cos{\theta}, y = r \sin{\theta}, t = \sqrt{1+r^2}.$$  I want to prove that the area element is

$$ dA=\frac{r dr d\theta}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}.$$

I consider a small sector $[\theta,\theta + \delta \theta] \times [r,r+\delta]$ in the $(\theta,r)$-plane and wish to show that the sector $S$ in the upper hyperboloid lying over it is close to a hyperbolic rectangle with length and sides equal to $$r \delta \theta \mbox{ and }  \frac{\delta r}{\sqrt{1+r^2}} .$$

The sector $S$ has four vertices, two of which are:
$$(\sqrt{1+r^2} , r \cos(\theta) , r \sin(\theta)) $$

and

$$(\sqrt{1+(r+\delta r)^2)}, (r+\delta r)\cos(\theta), (r+\delta r)\sin(\theta)). $$

I think the distance between these points should be close to $$ \frac{\delta r}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}.$$

I use the distance formula $d(P,Q) = \cosh^{-1}(- P \cdot_L Q)$ where $\cdot_L$ is the Lorentz product $a \cdot_L b = -a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 + a_3 b_3$.

I have computed the hyperbolic distance between the points above and it doesn't match what it should be in order to give the area element above.

What am I missing?

Comment: I haven't checked carefully, but am suspicious of the geometric description of a rectangle in the $(x,y)$-plane; instead, I'd take that rectangle in the $(r,\theta)$-plane and calculate the area of its image (which is presumably the meaning of the "target" formula). <> Separately, changing coordinates by $r = \sinh \rho$ looks likely to simplify the calculations.

Comment: Ah, yes, the $(r,\theta)$-plane.  Thanks.  And I did change coordinates so that $r = \sinh{\rho}$, which helped but did not lead to me to any new conclusions.  I get that the Lorentz product of the two vectors is: $$ \cosh{\rho} (\sqrt{\cosh^2{\rho} + (2\sinh{\rho}) \delta \rho} - \cosh{\rho}) - \sinh{\rho}(\cosh{\rho} )\delta \rho + 1 $$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a calculation in change-of-coordinates language. (The use of $r$ throughout may be simpler despite my comment; leaving that as an exercise. Also, it should be straightforward to use differentials and geometry to get the same result, though I haven't written up the details.)

In the parametrization $f(\rho, \theta) = (t, x, y)$ defined by
\begin{align*}
  t &= \cosh\rho, \\
  x &= \sinh\rho \cos\theta, \\
  y &= \sinh\rho \sin\theta,
\end{align*}
we have
\begin{align*}
  dt &= \sinh\rho\, d\rho, \\
  dx &= \cosh\rho \cos\theta\, d\rho - \sinh\rho \sin\theta\, d\theta, \\
  dy &= \cosh\rho \sin\theta\, d\rho + \sinh\rho \cos\theta\, d\theta.
\end{align*}
Consequently, the metric on the $(\rho, \theta)$ plane induced by the Lorentz/Minkowski metric $-dt^{2} + dx^{2} + dy^{2}$ is
\begin{align*}
  -(\sinh\rho\, d\rho)^{2}
  &+ (\cosh\rho \cos\theta\, d\rho - \sinh\rho \sin\theta\, d\theta)^{2} \\
  &+ (\cosh\rho \sin\theta\, d\rho + \sinh\rho \cos\theta\, d\theta)^{2} \\
  &= d\rho^{2} + \sinh^{2}\rho\, d\theta^{2}.
\end{align*}
If we set $r = \sinh\rho$, then $dr = \cosh\rho\, d\rho = \sqrt{1 + r^{2}}\, d\rho$, so
\begin{align*}
  d\rho^{2} + \sinh^{2}\rho\, d\theta^{2}
  &= \frac{dr^{2}}{1 + r^{2}} + r^{2}\, d\theta^{2} \\
  &= \biggl[\frac{dr}{\sqrt{1 + r^{2}}}\biggr]^{2} + [r\, d\theta]^{2}.
\end{align*}
The area element is the square root of the determinant, i.e.,
$$
dA = \frac{dr}{\sqrt{1 + r^{2}}} \times r\, d\theta
= \frac{r\, dr\, d\theta}{\sqrt{1 + r^{2}}}.
$$